# (How) To create subarray from dictionaries depends on certain key whether exists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
subarray = []
for dic in dics:
    if "TargetKey" in dic:
        subarray.append(dic)
```

This is the only thing I can think of now, how to combine them to one line ?
eg. I like this style:
`[dics["TargetKey"] for dic in dics]`

Trying to avoid create a new array variable, since I only need use once.

Appreciate for any advanced usage, studying more shortcut in python

Comment: it will be more readble if you add example of data in and out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on a one liner:

```
subarray = [dic for dic in dics if "TargetKey" in dic]
```

You can inline conditionals in list comprehensions. If you intend to use this once and iterate it use a generator:

```
subarray = (dic for dic in dics if "TargetKey" in dic)
```

Comment: ThankS! generator is a useful new type to me!

Answer (score 2):

```
subarray = list(filter(lambda x: 'TargetKey' in x,dics))
```